# RegEx in javascript. Allow only letters, comma and punctuation

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to make a RegEx for validating a form in javascript. The RegEx should only allow letters comma and punctuation. For instance I have this string:

```
Hi, this is a test of RegEx. Does it work
```

I've tried the following

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9,. ]{3,50}$/;
```

But it doesn't seems to work. Solutions?

Thanks!

EDIT:

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var RE_SSN = /^[A-Za-z0-9,. ]{3,50}$/; 

  function checkSsn(ssn){

   if (RE_SSN.test(ssn)) {
  alert("OK"); 
  javascript:addAppointment(document.forms[0])

    } else {
       alert("NO!");
   }
  }
  </script>

<div id="r">
    <label for="receipt">Receipt</label><input type="checkbox"     name="receipt" value="1"/>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Post it" onclick="checkSsn(this.form.content.value);"/>
```

Comment: Works for me. Please show us your actual code.

Comment: Does `this.form.content.value` actually contain anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to escape the "." as that is a special character in regex.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9,\. ]{3,50}$/;
```

Actually probably not.  Try using http://www.regextester.com/  - I was able to get it to work anyway.  Can you show us the full code for how you're implementing this?

Comment: . doesn't need to be escaped in character sequences ([]), I believe only - and ^ do

Answer (score 1):

if you want no punctuation at the beginning of the field:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\,\.\- ][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/
```

this also allows spaces (one scenario for this is last name - De La Hoya, or O'Doul)